# HTTP request issue Internal Server error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, https, aws-api-gateway

I am having issues with an HTTP response giving me a status code: 502, and error message: Internal Server Error. My setup is an AWS Lambda written in NodeJS making an HTTPS POST request to an AWS API Gateway integrated with another Lambda, as its backend.

The strange part is the Lambda acting as the backend of the API receives all the POST requests just fine and is able to execute its functions perfectly, but its callback responds to the other Lambda with an error.

Below is the callback on the lambda on the API Gateway side

```
    const done = (err, res) => callback(err, {
    statusCode: err ? JSON.stringify(err.code) : '200',
    body: err ? JSON.stringify(err.message) : JSON.stringify(res),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
});
```

And here is the code from the other lambda making an https POST request

```
            const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
                console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
                console.log('headers:', res.headers);


                res.on('data', (d) => {
                    process.stdout.write(d);
                });

                res.on('end', function () {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
                });
            });

            req.on('error', (e) => {
                console.error(e);
                console.log("request error");
            });


            req.write(JSON.stringify(payload));
            console.log("req.end");
            req.end();
```

I feel the problem is in these blocks of code because if I change the callback of the Lambda integrated API Gateway to hardcode the response to a 200 status code, then everything works fine.

Comment: Your API Lambda has some error, you need to debug that. Check the logs for that. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-mode-exceptions.html

Comment: First, check errors on Cloudwatch. Next, check your mapping templates (if you're not using Lambda-Proxy integration).

Answer (score 0):

Problem I see with your code is, if `err.code` is empty or invalid value, then you will get 502 on API Gateway. You need to fix the code so that it sends back a valid http response with a valid status code.

If your status code is invalid or empty then it will throw a 502 to the caller since the http response from lambda is invalid.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed now. No code changes were necessary but the problem was that the Lambda's Node.Js source files on the API Gateway side needed to be zipped with the necessary dependencies or node_modules as explained here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem of getting Internal server error while calling external API from lambda function.
Earlier **time out** for lambda function was **6sec** and I increased to some **25sec**. After that everything works fine.
Nodejs is asynchronous before getting API response next lines were executing irrespective of using async await.